# Craft 2.5 plugin sub navigation icons

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, plugin-craftcommerce

I notice that you can add icons for your sub navigation. However looking at the template for the subnav loop there isn't any markup to render that icon. Anyone know if this is coming in the future or missing code?

Example pulled from Craft Commerce plugin

```
$context['subnav']['settings'] = array('icon' => 'settings', 'label' => Craft::t('Settings'), 'url' => 'commerce/settings');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually possible. That `icon` key is not being used anywhere – just a remnant from a past feature idea that didn’t make it into Craft 2.5. (I just removed it for the next release.)